# Remove specific element from .CONFIG file

Tags: xml, string, powershell, parsing, config

I am trying to remove a specific element from a piece of software's config file.  It is formatted similar to an XML, which I have been able to parse before, but it seems to be a little different this time. As it doesn't really contain any sensitive info, I will just put the config file here up to the element I need to remove.  Sorry for the long post.

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
...
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<startup>
...
</startup>
<runtime>
...
</runtime>
<system.net>
...
</system.net>
<applicationSettings>
<SoD.Settings>
<!--  SpeechAnywhere Services (SAS) Server URL. 
            For the Nuance hosted SAS instance, use https://sas.nuancehdp.com/basic 
            For on-premise deployments specify a URL using the format (http|https)://your.server.instance:port/basic?mode=1  -->
<setting name="ServerURL" serializeAs="String">
...
</setting>
<!--  Organization token  -->
<setting name="OrganizationToken" serializeAs="String">
...
</setting>
<!--  Added Paragon Fix  -->
<setting name="RapidNavigationPrecisionTuning" serializeAs="String">
...
</setting>
<setting name="SupportedDomains" serializeAs="String">
...
</setting>
<setting name="SupportedAccounts" serializeAs="String">
...
</setting>
<!--  Please ensure that the microphones available to end users produce high quality sound. The list of microphones, 
      presented to users, should be short and limited to models recommended by Nuance or verified by you with the application. 
      If you have any questions, contact your Nuance Professional Services representative.  -->
<setting name="AllowedMicrophones" serializeAs="String">
...
</setting>
<!--  Languages in the IETF format. To present a list of available languages
                to the end user, specify all supported languages in the setting and separate them
                    with the pipe (|) character (for example, de-DE|en-US|sv-SE|nl-BE).  -->
<setting name="SupportedLanguages" serializeAs="String">
...
</setting>
<!--  Speech recognition topic(s). If you want to present a list of available speech recognition 
                 topics to the end user, specify all supported speech recognition topics in the setting and 
                   separate them with the pipe (|) character (for example, GeneralMedicine|Surgery).  -->
<setting name="SupportedTopics" serializeAs="String">
...
</setting>
<setting name="EULAHasBeenAcceptedByAllUsers" serializeAs="String">
...
</setting>
<!-- 
              Authentication (none/native/ldap/ldaplocal/trusted/sso/sso_adfs)
              none : No authentication (default)
              native : NMS Native 
              ldap : LDAP/AD
              ldaplocal : LDAP local authentication
              trusted : Trusted
              sso : SSO via Central Authentication
              sso_adfs : SSO via ADFS Authentication
               -->
<setting name="Authentication" serializeAs="String">
<value>trusted</value>
</setting>
```

I need to remove the 'Trusted' value at the very end, but cant seem to figure out a way to find it.  I am still very new to all of this. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your post to show in code, what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If that value **always** exists on its own line, then you might as well just cut it rather than parse the xml:

```sh
# element to remove
$string = '<value>trusted</value>'

# get all lines except the trusted element
$edited = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\file.config' | Where {$_ -NE $string}

# write back to file
$edited | Out-File 'C:\path\to\file.config'
```

Comment: Thanks! ended up just creating the corrected config file and had the script simply switch them out, but thanks for the response.